# typescript - Property 'inputValues' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputValueType[]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

There is an error I get

```
TypeError: inputValues.map is not a function
```

In `<InputGroup/>`, it shows warning

```
Type '{ inputValues: InputValueType[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputValueType[]'.
  Property 'inputValues' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputValueType[]'.ts
```

How to fix it?

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, ChangeEvent } from "react";

import type { NextPage } from "next";

type InputValueType = {
  id: number;
  value: string;
};

const InputGroup = (inputValues: Array<InputValueType>): JSX.Element => {
  var rows: Array<any> = [];
  inputValues.map((inputValue: InputValueType) => {
    console.log(inputValues);
  });
  return <>{rows}</>;
};

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<Array<InputValueType>>([
    { id: 0, value: "" },
    { id: 1, value: "" },
    { id: 2, value: "" },
    { id: 3, value: "" },
    { id: 4, value: "" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <InputGroup inputValues={inputValues} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-077l4z?file=/src/App.tsx:0-761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering the single attribute `inputValues` to be the whole prop object. In reality it is just one on of the keys of the prop object being passed.

Usually one defines an interface for props and adds custom keys inside it to pass them down to child components.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, ChangeEvent } from "react";

import type { NextPage } from "next";

type InputValueType = {
  id: number;
  value: string;
};

interface InputGroupProps {
  inputValues: Array<InputValueType>;
}
const InputGroup = ({ inputValues }: InputGroupProps): JSX.Element => {
  var rows: Array<any> = [];
  inputValues.map((inputValue: InputValueType) => {
    console.log(inputValue);
  });
  return <>{rows}</>;
};

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<InputValueType[]>([
    { id: 0, value: "" },
    { id: 1, value: "" },
    { id: 2, value: "" },
    { id: 3, value: "" },
    { id: 4, value: "" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <InputGroup inputValues={inputValues} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Above I have extracted the `inputValues` key out of the props object using [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Playground Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-t7983z?file=/src/App.tsx)

Another simple way it can be achieved is wihout using an interface and directly using the `props` object, which is what I feel you were going for. Here again `destructuring` will be used.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, ChangeEvent } from "react";

import type { NextPage } from "next";

type InputValueType = {
  id: number;
  value: string;
};

const InputGroup = ({
  inputValues
}: {
  inputValues: Array<InputValueType>;
}): JSX.Element => {
  var rows: Array<any> = [];
  inputValues.map((inputValue: InputValueType) => {
    console.log(inputValue);
  });
  return <>{rows}</>;
};

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<Array<InputValueType>>([
    { id: 0, value: "" },
    { id: 1, value: "" },
    { id: 2, value: "" },
    { id: 3, value: "" },
    { id: 4, value: "" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <InputGroup inputValues={inputValues} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[Playground Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-2wgpzw?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Also you probably want to `log(inputValue)` and not `inputValues` so i have done that. Not related to the question tho

Answer (score 1):

You needed to destruct the 'props' parameter of the 'InputGroup' component to use the 'inputValues' property.

```
type InputGroupProps = {
  inputValues: Array<InputValueType>
}

const InputGroup = ({ inputValues }: InputGroupProps): JSX.Element => {
  var rows: Array<any> = [];
  inputValues.map((inputValue: InputValueType) => {
    console.log(inputValue);
  });
  return <>{rows}</>;
};
```

Anything passed as an attribute in the '' tag will end up inside props (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass ***({inputValues}: {inputValues: Array})*** as the props for you're InputGroup component.

```
  const InputGroup = ({inputValues}: {inputValues: Array<InputValueType>}):JSX.Element => {

  var rows: Array<any> = [];
  inputValues.map((inputValue: InputValueType) => {
     console.log(inputValue);
  });

  return <>{rows}</>;
};
```